# SQL Server: quickly retrieve row count for large table using where query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Sorry guys, I just check question now: I have a large table containing more than 30,000,000 rows.I needed a quick and reliable way to count the number of rows contained within this table.

A good approach is:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx

but it's for **WHOLE** table. My SQL statement looks like:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from HistoryData 
where Port = 6021 
  and RecvTime > '2015-04-13' 
  and RecvTime < '2015-04-14 15:00:00'
```

This result of this query is 18615883

- CPU time is **3094 ms**
- Duration time is **30429 ms**

My table has an index on (`RecvTime, Port`).The index script is:

```
/****** Script Date: 04/14/2015 15:54:04 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HistoryData] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_HistoryData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Port] ASC,
    [RecvTime] ASC
)
```

Can I reduce the consuming time in 5000ms or less?

The SQL execution plan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsYVb.jpg

Comment: Do you have an index on the column mycol. if you don't have an index on mycol, add one

Comment: Do you have an index on mycol? if your condition is fixed (i mean if XXX and xxxx are around the same numbers all of the time) you might want to have a where clause on that index

Comment: `select count(mycol) from MyTable where mycol>XXX and mycol < xxxx` and create index on mycol. if you have an index then query wont scan entire table.

Comment: Try selecting count(Port) instead of count(*). I'm not sure it will help but it's worth the 30 seconds to test

Comment: @AmbareeshSurendran thanks, my table have an index

Comment: @ZoharPeled my table only have three columns

Comment: doesn't matter how many columns you have, it's an attempt to save the aggregate (7%) time. You might want to consider changing the order of fields in your index also.

Comment: According to the execution plan your indices to `Port` and `RecvTime` are not applied. It's scanning the PK index. It means the definition of indices doesn't match the `where` clause you defined. And +1 to @Sameer. Don't even mention `count(*)` when you're saying you optimize the query. At least use `count(1)`. Mind that a separate index for `Port` and another one for `RectTime` won't work. You need an aggregate index with both of columns to fit this exact `where` clause

Comment: How do(es) your index(es) look like, maybe it's just the case that you need an index on `Port, RecvTime` instead of `RecvTime, Port`?

Comment: from my experience, and your table structure as I see, probably you are on wrong hosting for your need. If you have index okay it is not aggregated, but you still have those, and you have done few things already, it only tells your hardware is lacking, adding more RAM will surely help here.  you can try Count(Port) (index field) with between maybe.

Comment: @SumitGupta +1 I make a test on another computer, the duration time is much less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try such a structure for your index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_HistoryData] ON [dbo].[HistoryData]
(
    [Port] ASC,
    [RecvTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Your Execution plan should look like [image: this plan] Mind the referenced `IX_HistoryData` not `PK_HistoryData`

PS. Your table is very simple, and I could easily create data for test, but I only have a local SQL Server (running on SSD) and results won't be relevant anyway.

Comment: Thank for your advice, My Index has the same structure. I change another computer as server, the result is better.

Comment: @yubaolee there must be a reason for SQL SERVER not to use that index. Otherwise it would be stated in your execution plan.